# PAM authenticate a user in C

Tags: c, pam

Ok, so I'm a pretty awful coder, and I'm wondering (as the title says) how I can authenticate a Linux user with PAM using C. The only thing I really understand is including the `pam_appl.h` and `pam_misc.h` header files, that I need to place `pam_start` and `pam_end` somewhere in my code, and not much else. So how would I achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: This guide might help? http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/Linux-PAM_ADG.html

Comment: Better to post what your have tried in "somewhere in my code".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `pam_authenticate` function.

Working with PAM requires answers that are a bit longer than the average StackOverflow answer; but, fortunately there is an entire online book on the subject http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/Linux-PAM_ADG.html

If you want to just get a code snippet, you can start with this one

```
#include <security/pam_appl.h>
#include <security/pam_misc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static struct pam_conv conv = {
    misc_conv,
    NULL
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pam_handle_t *pamh=NULL;
    int retval;
    const char *user="nobody";

    if(argc == 2) {
        user = argv[1];
    }

    if(argc > 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: check_user [username]\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    retval = pam_start("check_user", user, &conv, &pamh);

    if (retval == PAM_SUCCESS)
        retval = pam_authenticate(pamh, 0);    /* is user really user? */

    if (retval == PAM_SUCCESS)
        retval = pam_acct_mgmt(pamh, 0);       /* permitted access? */

    /* This is where we have been authorized or not. */

    if (retval == PAM_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Authenticated\n");
    } else {
        fprintf(stdout, "Not Authenticated\n");
    }

    if (pam_end(pamh,retval) != PAM_SUCCESS) {     /* close Linux-PAM */
        pamh = NULL;
        fprintf(stderr, "check_user: failed to release authenticator\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return ( retval == PAM_SUCCESS ? 0:1 );       /* indicate success */
}
```

Which will work with a correct PAM setup including

```
  You need to add the following (or equivalent) to the
  /etc/pam.d/check_user file:
  # check authorization
  auth       required     pam_unix.so
  account    required     pam_unix.so
 */
```

as detailed within the mentioned book.  The original source of this code snippet can be found at http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/adg-example.html

Comment: Greatly helpful. However i would like to give an existing passphrase to PAM, rather than making an input through the password prompt PAM gives me. The closest thing i could find in the book is `PAM_AUTHTOK`, but the book says it's ignored by everything other than `pam_sm_authenticate` and `pam_sm_chauthtok`, unless i'm being stupid which is the more likely case.

Comment: PAM doesn't concern itself with where the passphrases come from.  But, if you want to store an authenticated session, PAM_AUTHTOK is what you store.  Of course these sessions don't last forever; but, assuming the session hasn't timed out, you load the previously saved session information from disk and then use pam_sm_chauthtok to replace the current authorization (or lack of authorization).  If you want to store and reused passphrases, that's not a feature (I think) than the authorization subsystem provides, in fact, it's sort of a feature that obviously shouldn't be pam_authenticate.

Comment: Got there in the end. Had to make a custom function for pam_conv, but it worked. Thanks for your help.