# How do I request user to enter a correct password until it gets true

Tags: c

```
switch(res)
{
   case 1:
   printf("Enter password: ");
   scanf("%s", password);
   int value=strcmp(rpassword , password);//when comparing strings

   if(value==0)
   {
       printf("Welcome to the Hospital Management system \n");
   }
   else
   {
       printf("Re-Enter Password \n");   
   }
   break;

   default:
   printf("Welcome \n");
   break;
}
```

Comment: So what's wrong with your code? Does it compile? Does it run? If it runs what happens? Where is the rest of the relevant code? Read this [ask] and this [mcve]. That being said, you probably need a loop.

Comment: I want to know how to request again from the user if he had entered incorrect password, like loop

Comment: You are going to need some form of loop. Keep looping until the password is correct.  Something like: `do { ... } while (value != 0)`

Comment: switch(res)
   {
       case 1:
      
       while (x!=0)
    {
      printf("\nInput the password: ");
      scanf("%s",password); 
 
     int value = strcmp(rpassword,password); 
        if (value==0)
       {
      printf("Welcome to the Hospital Management system \n");
      x=0;
          }
         else
          {
            printf("Wrong password, try another");       
       }
 
        }
       break;

Comment: @RSD Please don't use comments to add requested information or to show changes to your original question. [edit] your question instead and make clear what you have added/changed. BTW: For security considerations, a real program should not allow unlimited attempts to enter a password, and it should not store cleartext passwords. If the password does not match, the user might have typed the username wrong, so he/she might need a chance to enter a new username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `do-while` loop as follows:

```
int value;
do
{
   printf("Enter password: ");
   scanf("%s", password);
   
   value=strcmp(rpassword , password);//when comparing strings

   if(value==0)
   {
       printf("Welcome to the Hospital Management system \n");
   }
   else
   {
       printf("Re-Enter Password \n");   
   }
} while(value != 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that.

Seriously, you need to make your operating system or dedicated libraries handle it, don't mess with passwords.

In your program you would need to:

- not hardwire the password (do not have a global variable or a `#define`,
  otherwise the password is
  retrivable by searching it with `strings`, disassembler/decompiler or hex-editors).
- hash it, if you save it on the disk, save the hash of the password, do not
  check directly with strcmp, it mean that you're saving it in clear-text,
  which is a deprecated procedure from a lot of time.
- manage to have an anti brute-force mechanism
- don't use `scanf("%s", input);`, it would open your program to buffer
  overflows, because you're not checking the length of the input.

and some other details that your operating system is already taking in
consideration (e.g. with PAM).

I think that you want to generally handle a wrong string input, to do so you need
to do something like the following:

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int r = 0;
        char buffer[5];
        do {
                printf("Enter yes: ");
                fflush(stdout);
                fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
                buffer[3] = '\0';

                printf("User inserted %s\n", buffer);

                r = strcmp("yes", buffer);
                if (r != 0)
                        printf("please say yes\n");
        } while (r != 0);

        printf("Welcome\n");

        return 0;
}
```

If you need to read a password, please use a stronger and tested method, such as PAM on Linux
similar to this answer: [PAM authenticate a user in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64184960/pam-authenticate-a-user-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

You can run an infinte loop like this : while(1)
And if the password is correct just break the loop else it will continue to ask the user.